# Convert list to int array in C#

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio-2012, int

I have searched through StackOverflow and Google for the conversion, but unfortunately I was unable to get the solution. Everything was the opposite of what I wanted. i.e., Conversion of an `int[]` to `List`.

**Problem**

I have this code in my `[WebMethod]`.

```
[WebMethod]
public int MyMethodWS(int N, List<int> M)
{
}
```

And now I have a **Console Application**, that references this service by using this URL:

```
http://localhost:61090/MyMethod.asmx?WSDL
```

I have this code in my Console Application:

```
int N;
List<int> M = new List<int>();
// Some crazy user input coding.
// Ultimately you will have non-empty M list and N int.
MyMethod.MyMethodWS DA = new MyMethod.MyMethodWS();
Sum = DA.MyMethodWS(N, M);
```

When I run this code, I am getting this error:

> **#1:** The best overloaded method match for '`MyMethod.MyMethod.MyMethodWS(int, int[])`' has some invalid arguments.
>
> **#2:** Argument 2: cannot convert from '`System.Collections.Generic.List<int>`' to '`int[]`'

**Questions**

1. I have used only `List` there. But why is it trying to convert as `int[]`?
2. Currently the WebService as well as Console Application, both run in the same Solution. Is it a problem? Should I use different solutions, or different instances of Visual Studio 2012 altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is trying to convert it to `int[]`, because `MyMethodWS` takes a `int[]` as a parameter, instead of `List<int>` that you are trying to pass it. To convert a `List<int>` to `int[]`, call `List<T>.ToArray();`

So change the line `Sum = DA.MyMethodWS(N, M);` to `Sum = DA.MyMethodWS(N, M.ToArray());`

Comment: What makes you say it takes an `int[]` parameter? Could you explain why this is the case, even though it's defined as `List<int>`?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Actually I'm a bit confused now too. I think originally the method that Praveen was trying to call was named `DivisorSumWS` or something, and not that `MyMethodWS` which clearly takes a `List<int>` as a parameter. However, that error message clearly states that the method takes `int[]` as a parameter... I'm not quite sure whats going on, maybe Praveen changed the original post or I read it incorrectly to begin with.

Comment: @JaakkoLipsanen Please update your answer. Yes, I changed it because well, it is the code from my production, which I am not supposed to put. :)

Comment: The thing is, I have declared as `List<int>`, but it expects in `int[]`. But your solution worked removing the errors, but VS 2012 Crashed.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Do you still have a problem or error in your code? Because based on the edited code from your question, it should work jus fine. If it's still not working, try to clean&rebuild and if even that doesn't help, post more information so that we can help you.

Comment: No error. VS 2012 Crashed. That's the issue now. @JaakkoLipsanen

Comment: @PraveenKumar Does it crash everytime when you open/try to run it? I have no idea what could cause it, there changes to code (at least "normal things" like these) could cause VS to crash.

Comment: No idea, buddy! :( BTW, am running in a VM instance. :D